# HUD not working in LibreOffice downloaded from libreoffice.org

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

As I want all the latest software for my computer, I downloaded LibreOffice from the site, not from Software Center. I followed the instructions on how to install it. I have only one problem; the <kbd>alt</kbd> function, which has the ability of fast finding the meny entry or function inside the program, does not work. Here's an example of that function in Chrome:

[image: search results]

However, if I do that in LibreOffice, I get nothing:

[image: no search results]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibreOffice in Ubuntu 14.04's repositories is already the latest version, so you already had the latest version installed when you installed Ubuntu 14.04.

The HUD features come only from Ubuntu's LibreOffice packages as they ship their own patches for software to use the HUD.

PS: Install libreoffice-style-sifr, it looks a lot prettier than the human icon theme.

Comment: I have checked and they're NOT the same versions. In software center libreoffice is older!

Comment: Being older by one minor point release is not the end of the world. Trusty ships with LibreOffice 4.2.3 when the latest stable version is 4.2.4. In due time, Trusty will have 4.2.4 when it is proven to be stable. As a note, never install software outside of the software repository if you can help it. There is usually a PPA from the developers that ships packages packaged specifically for Ubuntu. In LibreOffice's case, there is the LibreOffice PPA that currently ships LibreOffice 4.2.4.